# get selected date from Pikadate (datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm currently trying to implement PikaDate into my website to allow a user to select a date, to then be set to a variable.

At the moment the calendar loads fine and the user can select the date. The problem I'm having is I cannot seem to retrieve the selected date. Looking through the documentation it suggests I use picker.toString('YYYY-MM-DD') but adding that seems to break it.

The html is simply a text input field with the id as "datepicker".

The javascript im trying is as follows:

```
<script>
var picker = new Pikaday({     
 firstDay: 1,
 minDate: moment().add({days: 20}).toDate(),
 disableDayFn: function(date){// Disable Monday 
    return date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6;},
 field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
 format: 'D MMM YYYY'   
});
 var selectedday =  document.getElementById('datepicker').val ;
</script>
```

When i process the form the result i get is "undefined", it seems like im making a really basic mistake here but everything I've tried hasn't worked, can anyone see the issue?

many thanks!

Comment: try document.getElementById('datepicker').val();

Comment: unfortunately that hasn't worked, or atleast by changing it to your suggestion, the javascript on the page no longer works (unresponsive), thanks though!

Comment: @SambathKumarS—can you show where the *val* method of DOM elements is defined? Elements may have a *value* property though, so `document.getElementById('datepicker').value` may work as expected, or if using jQuery `$('#datepicker').val()`.

Comment: neither 

var selectedday =  dodocument.getElementById('datepicker').value  ; 

or

var selectedday =  $('#datepicker').val()  ; 

have worked for me, sorry